# Does a wave effect remain in spacetime at the quantum level?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, atomic-physics

In *Bohr's atomic model*, the circumference of an electron orbit is always positive integral of the electron's wavelength. Here is an image:

[image]

The circumference of an electron's orbit is always a positive integral to its wavelength because the electron doesn't interfere with it own and doesn't destroys itself. But, how the electron wave will intefere with it own if it goes through the orbit. It is only possible if there is wave remaining in its path. So, does a wave effect remain in spacetime at the quantum level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we apply the de Broglie hypotesis to Bohr's atomic model we have to remember that the quantized orbits represent *stationary states*.

If we want to view electrons in such states as waves these will have to be *stationary waves*.

Skipping over the mathematics$^1$, this means that the wave is in the same location at any time, it does not flee "following" the electron Bohr had imagined populated the orbit. If the orbit's length isn't an integer multiple of the wavelength there could be destructive interference in some regions, at the very least.

We can make a quick example if we picture the particle as a sinusoidal wave of wavelength L "looped around" a circumference of length $\frac {3} {2}L = L + \frac {1} {2}L$
The first time we go around our loop we encounter no issue but on our second go we realize that the first L/2 piece of the wave has opposite sign with respect to our first go (draw a picture to make this clear visually). This is an example of the destructive effects of self interference.

---

$^1$<sub>A stationary wave implies conditions on the length of the occupied region which generalize this discussion</sub>

Comment: By the way why is the wave doesn't go with the electron if it is associated with the electron?

Comment: When de Broglie published its result picturing a standing wave was required to produce the correct results (what we observed).He did not bother to explain why,  if you think about it when we talk of wave associated to a particle what do we mean? What oscillates?.Today we know that it does non make sense to talk a about  "where" the particle is because it is "distributed" in space in the sense that in can be found everywhere with some probability. You could see the standing wave assumption as an anticipation of this. The electron is, in some sense, not running along the orbit but "smeared"